# Como puedo buscar en un diccionario de python al utilizar div

Tags: python, python-3.x

Código:

```
def encontrar_pelicula(nombre_pelicula: str, p1: dict, p2: dict, p3: 
    dict, p4: dict,  p5: dict) -> dict:
    
    nom_peli = input("Ingrese el nombre de la pelicula: ")
    p1 = dict(pelicula1)
    p2 = dict(pelicula2)
    p3 = dict(pelicula3)
    p4 = dict(pelicula4)
    p4 = dict(pelicula5)
    
    pelicula = encontrar_pelicula(nom_peli,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5)
    if pelicula is None:
        print("No hay ninguna pelicula con este nombre")
    
    
    return  nom_peli

print(mostrar_informacion_pelicula(pelicula1))

nom_peli = input("Ingrese el nombre de la pelicula: ")
encontrar_pelicula(nom_peli)
```

Comment: Que??? Podrías aclarar tu pregunta por favor? Lee [ask]

Comment: La función `encontrar_película` siempre retorna el nombre ingresado por el usuario, nunca `None`, por lo que el `if` es redundante.

Comment: `encontrar_película` es una función recursiva sin condición de termino; nunca retornara.

Comment: `pelicula1`, 2, 3, 4, 5 no están definidas en ninguna parte. Los diccionarios que creas no los usas para nada.

Comment: Pides dos veces el nombre de la película.

Comment: En la última llamada a `encontrar_pelicula` faltan los parámetros p1, p2, p3, p4, p5